# how to start observable after x sec

Tags: rx-java, deferred

what's the best way to start observable after let's say 10 sec?

```
Single<Boolean> init();

public void onStart() {
    init().subscribe(getMySubscriber())
}
```

I'd like to make the actual work in `init starts after 10 sec since subscribed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `delaySubscription` delaying a subscription to an existing source:

```
Single.just(1)
   .delaySubscription(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
   .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

If your `init()` method itself has side-effects before returning a Single, you can wrap it with `Single.defer` and the above structure should still work:

```
Single.defer(() -> init())
    .delaySubscription(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Observable.timer()` is what you're looking for

```
Observable
            .timer(10L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .subscribe(aLong -> init());
```